# Compact-open topology on $\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{R}(V,W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional real vector spaces, and I give $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,W) \cong V^* \otimes W$ its usual vector space topology. Does this agree with the subspace topology induced by the inclusion $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,W) \subset C^0(V,W)$, where $C^0(V,W)$ has the compact open topology, and $V$ and $W$ are given their vector space topologies?

> **Attempt:** Think about the operator norm on $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,W)$. A neighborhood basis of at $T
>  \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}}(V,W)$ are those linear
>   transformations $R$ such that $\|T - R\| < \epsilon$, or equivalently,
>   $\|T(v) - R(v)\| < \epsilon$ for all $v \in V$ of norm $1$. Given some particular $\epsilon$, how can I
>   find finitely many subsets $K_\alpha, U_\alpha$ such that $\cap_\alpha
>  C(K_\alpha, U_\alpha)$ lands inside $\{R : \|T-R\| <\epsilon\}$?

What if I let one or both of the spaces be infinite-dimensional? How does the compact-open topology compare to the various operator norms?

Comment: In the case of finite dimension, yes. In finite dimension topological vector spaces, every isomorphism is a homeomorphism. The identity in a vector space is a isomorphism, hence you have your result.

If one or both are not finite dimensional, first of all we don't have $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}} (V,W) \subset C^0(V,W)$. Secondly, you must tell what topologies you are considering. However, I don't know any general result.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo When you say that any isomorphism is a homeomorphism, aren't you assuming that the topology is given by the vector space structure? But that fact would be equivalent to what I'm asking. (Sorry if I'm missing something.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "the topology is given by the vector space structure". What I mean is that, given any two topological vector spaces of the same dimension $X,Y$ (that is, the topology on $X$ and $Y$ are only assumed to be Hausdorff and to make the sum and multiplication by scalar continuous), then any isomorphism between them is a homeomorphism. If you have two different topologies on a vector space $X$, if both of them make $X$ a TVS, then the identity will therefore be a homeomorphism. This fact is a consequence of Theorem $1.21$ of Rudin's FA.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo Is it clear that the addition and scaling operations are continuous with respect to the compact-open topology?